# Xerces-C++ XMLString::patternMatch() not functioning correctly

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces-c

I'm trying to find a way to match strings in C++ against XML Schema regular expressions. The [XML Schema regex grammar](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) is not supported by `std::regex` so I installed the `Xerces-C++` XML library to use its pattern matching functionality. Unfortunately even with a basic example, it doesn't seem to work right.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>

using namespace XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    }
    catch (const XMLException& ex)
    {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(ex.getMessage());
        std::cerr << "Error during Xerces-c Initialization.\n"
            << "  Exception message:"
            << message;
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return 1;
    }

    const XMLCh* str = XMLString::transcode("bcdfg");

    // Implement a simple regex that uses "character class subtraction"
    // Should match any string that does not contain vowels
    const XMLCh* pattern = XMLString::transcode("[a-z-[aeiuo]]+");

    if (XMLString::patternMatch(str, pattern) != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Match!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No match." << std::endl;
    }

    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
No Match.

If I write a very simple regex that doesn't use character class subtraction it does seem to work. But the issue is I *need* character class subtraction to work because I need to support any possible regex that conforms to the XML Schema regex grammar.

The documentation for Xerces is very unclear and doesn't specify which regex grammar is used by this function, but I was assuming since it is an XML parsing library it would implement XML regular expressions. Perhaps that assumption was wrong?

### EDIT:

Adding an example of an actual regex from an XSD file that I will need to support. This example comes from the schema that defines the basic datatypes supported by XML Schemas. The specification can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#conformance

An example of a regular expression I will need to parse that uses character class subtraction (as well as the special `\c` and `\i` character groups is shown in the `xs:pattern` restriction for the "NCName" datatype below:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="NCName" id="NCName">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation source="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#NCName"/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:Name">
      <xs:pattern value="[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*" id="NCName.pattern">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation
               source="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-NCName">
            pattern matches production 4 from the Namespaces in XML spec
          </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Not every parsing situation is a good candidate for a regular expression.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I made it clear, I'm not trying to parse XML files themselves, I'm just trying to parse strings using the XML Schema regex grammar.

Comment: Your intent is still unclear.   Are you wanting to support regex features beyond that specified by [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#regexs)?  That would not be advisable as it would no longer be standard XSD.

Comment: @kjhughes, I am looking for a way to support exactly those features and nothing more. Character class subtraction is part of XML Schema regular expressions. I've been struggling for weeks trying to find a way to support XML Schema regex within C++ and I was hopeful that a dedicated XML parsing library like Xerces would work for this :(

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add an XSD that uses a regex that you claim abides by the W3C standard but which is not supported by Xerces?  The smallest such XSD and accompanying XML document instance that exhibits the issue would be ideal.

Comment: The regex I tried to use in the main function is a very basic example of a regex that is supported by XML Schema regex, but not standard regex. But as an additional example I have attached a snippet from an xsd file that contains a pattern that uses character class subtraction as well.

Comment: I was thinking you were trying to fix some behavior, but I see now that you're trying to extract some behavior to use in another setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I wasn't able to get the `Xerces` regular expressions to work, and the documentation was nothing short of abysmal, so I decided to try out another library. `libxml2` has XML regular expressions and although the documentation for the regex feature was similarly abysmal, I was able to get a working program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml/xmlregexp.h>

int main()
{
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION;

    xmlChar* str = xmlCharStrdup("bcdfg");
    xmlChar* pattern = xmlCharStrdup("[a-z-[aeiou]]+");
    xmlRegexp* regex = xmlRegexpCompile(pattern);

    if (xmlRegexpExec(regex, str) == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Match!" << std::endl;
    }

    free(regex);
    free(pattern);
    free(str);
}
```

**Output:**

Match!

I figured even though it does not answer how to get regular expressions to work properly with `Xerces`, this answer may help others who are looking to solve the same problem of getting XML Schema regular expressions to work in C++.